# Can anyone provide a simple example of starting an OSGi application via main()

Tags: java, osgi

I'm building an osgi application using Equinox.
For this purpose i ordered the book 'OSGi and Equinox' from the eclipse series.
The book describes a way for an OSGi application to be started with an entry point like main().

The problem is, that i don't understand this section in this book, because the chapter of this book describes an already finished example and does not give any instructions how to set up such a behaviour.

Can anyone help me, please?

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on this subject: http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html

Note that the API used in that blog post is standard OSGi, therefore can be used with any OSGi framework including Equinox.

Answer (score 1):

Take also a look at http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html